# Doing multiple ttests within a dataframe.

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I would like to do a series of ttests on a dataset:

specifically, i'd like to do seperate ttest for rats 1-5 vs 6-10 for every gene.

I've tried to do this:

```
>goi2 <- (goi[-1])
control <- goi2[1:5,]
stress <- goi2[6:10,]

for (i in 1:92){
  x <- control[,i]
  y <- stress[,i]
  x <= t.test(x, y)
 # print(x=i)
}
```

but i get this error:

> Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing

I've tried a few varieties of this but cant figure out why this wont work.

Im a complete newb to R, but not programming in general.

Dataset:

---

> Gene,Rat_1,Rat_2,Rat_3,Rat_4,Rat_5,Rat_6,Rat_7,Rat_8,Rat_9,Rat_10
>   Oprd1,2.746,1.387,2.25,3.363,3.191,2.432,1.985,1.75,2.752,1.771
>   Grin2a,3.134,2.644,2.962,5.168,2.484,3.54,2.596,1.535,3.197,2.232
>   Grin2d(2),4.496,5.528,2.631,4.684,3.934,6.047,0.98,0.077,4.381,2.327
>   Oprm1,1.998,1.804,1.611,1.712,3.672,3.215,0.249,1.248,1.758,2.671
>   Scn2b,137.35,97.158,113.65,141.93,77.295,133.02,88.872,75.586,108.96,97.626
>   Ntf3,0.989,1.835,1.604,1.133,0.889,0.782,0.918,2.241,2.216,3.921
>   Scn1a(2),9.224,7.369,10.145,14.242,17.262,11.535,8.144,7.166,13.625,6.604
>   Ntrk2(2),21.929,17.018,14.799,19.783,14.632,24.421,14.235,9.344,16.658,17.913
>   Cacna1c,4.585,3.637,3.948,4.135,3.403,5.381,4.193,3.162,3.455,3.695
>   Grin2b,3.273,2.57,2.101,2.922,1.826,3.338,2.121,1.416,2.973,2.005
>   Scn9a(2),0.319,0,0,0.453,0.434,0.376,0,0,0.346,0.469
>   Gria4(2),10.867,8.156,7.889,9.236,14.134,10.574,8.404,8.179,9.442,7.982
>   Cacna1e(2),1.805,1.783,2.045,1.968,1.405,1.807,0.973,0.993,0.857,1.769
>   Gria3,4.237,4.188,3.901,5.221,6.439,3.993,3.421,4.012,4.452,4.631
>   Gria1,8.284,7.942,7.557,12.001,3.976,9.472,7.653,4.16,7.971,5.381
>   Kcnj5,3.089,2.046,3.332,3.392,2.168,3.786,3.865,1.414,2.37,2.009
>   Cacna1b(2),11.071,8.716,8.246,9.594,7.189,11.62,6.028,4.481,9.307,9.074
>   Scn5a,1.301,1.017,0.714,1.401,0.449,1.183,1.065,0.292,0.823,0.714
>   Scn2a(2),3.286,2.119,2.257,2.024,1.902,3.441,1.327,1.072,2.576,2.09
>   Scn10a,0.037,0.069,0.087,0.076,0.082,0.095,0.052,0.019,0.078,0.045
>   Cacna1g(2),6.543,5.095,5.463,8.404,3.084,7.359,5.746,4.682,5.969,4.315
>   Cacna1e(3),5.37,4.002,3.313,4.803,2.665,5.623,3.296,1.953,3.827,4.092
>   Bdnf(4),0.869,0.509,0.996,1.032,0.256,0.742,0.498,0.531,0.994,0.473
>   Scn4a,0.284,0.278,0.359,0.45,0.761,0.31,0.319,0.27,0.366,0.273
>   Scn5a(2),0.256,0.477,0.587,0.283,0,0.564,0.044,0.023,0.204,0.15
>   Gabra1,51.019,44.3,57.609,81.522,40.853,64.921,68.263,31.766,58.006,39.518
>   Scn8a,6.854,14.666,5.416,12.347,4.823,14.935,7.014,16.684,9.686,17.44
>   Kcnj3,17.047,14.3,13.741,14.363,14.01,13.268,12.172,10.718,15.374,13.048
>   Slc6a2,107.9,69.941,91.704,36.411,112.57,114.5,23.398,63.848,53.323,135.26
>   Grin3a,6.952,5.676,7.301,12.557,3.65,10.628,9.783,4.286,8.015,4.499
>   Cnr1,20.261,16.981,19.996,26.469,12.709,24.705,25.548,10.61,19.746,14.64
>   Scn1b,13.732,15.763,5.03,20.68,17.788,14.959,16.298,24.682,22.477,15.117
>   Gria1(2),2.709,3.667,2.51,2.9,2.134,1.93,4.308,2.59,2.487,1.742
>   Scn3a(2),1.439,2.614,0,0.352,0,1.358,1.027,0,0.452,0.586
>   Scn11a,0.058,0.292,0.036,0.127,0.058,0.06,0.074,0.164,0.047,0.05
>   Gria1(3),25.283,17.779,22.725,32.705,8.823,28.727,26.915,12.876,23.545,17.879
>   Cacna1f,0.056,0.067,0.14,0.123,0.04,0.182,0.072,0.083,0.077,0.097
>   Cacna1a,20.791,19.816,17.613,21.663,15.697,22.824,16.737,16.719,16.604,20.469
>   Gria4,8.51,7.107,8.342,9.338,7.46,8.877,7.673,6.341,8.393,9.555
>   Scn8a,6.738,14.706,4.172,11.467,2.552,10.757,6.021,15.222,3.588,11.333
>   Grin2d,20.398,15.794,22.521,24.693,16.97,24.108,24.19,21.016,18.314,19.044
>   Gria3(2),15.301,13.087,13.918,14.433,12.282,14.914,12.198,11.602,13.738,15.481
>   Oprk1(2),6.66,4.97,7.604,10.281,2.151,10.462,10.278,1.525,6.869,4.902
>   Scn1b(3),46.553,42.795,49.498,55.558,64.101,38.178,44.1,59.033,43.837,39.382
>   Cacna1h,9.145,7.295,8.7,8.028,5.415,10.799,8.21,6.332,8.455,7.683
>   Scn2a,36.803,29.975,30.609,38.334,19.053,39.127,31.146,23.066,30.896,32.345
>   Cacna1g,5.489,5.213,6.24,7.896,3.97,4.876,6.283,5.464,6.08,3.692
>   Ntrk2(3),147.81,152.45,153.46,136.09,181.1,156.85,219.8,164.53,156.64,147.92
>   Scn1a,9.222,9.162,9.659,13.83,12.679,8.088,11.45,10.406,9.503,6.827
>   Grin1(3),69.943,68.01,76.358,81.029,63.692,83.424,70.981,80.088,69.821,70.764
>   Grin3b(2),2.065,1.265,1.45,1.576,3.875,1.441,1.822,1.964,2.286,0.965
>   Gabra2(2),2.268,1.251,1.638,2.844,2.93,2.934,3.725,1.724,1.455,2.674
>   Scn1b2(2),161.76,164.24,213.24,209.19,235.38,172.98,207.33,216.96,198.26,130.93
>   Oprm1(2),4.046,5.181,2.362,1.925,0.806,2.232,1.178,1.491,3.259,3.751
>   Cacna1c(3),0.077,0.194,0.23,0,0.132,0.127,0,0.035,0.09,0.092
>   Ntrk2,27.139,26.028,23.881,27.22,22.259,30.728,22.381,19.782,24.704,30.85
>   Cacna1d(2),2.126,2.263,2.038,2.1,1.995,2.966,1.943,2.01,2.317,2.214
>   Scn3a,21.272,16.356,16.245,14.875,11.825,19.753,10.994,11.08,16.905,19.832
>   Grin1(2),76.771,65.788,66.059,78.716,33.91,88.228,73.859,47.717,70.674,61.275
>   Grina,672.31,705.45,679.04,623.4,597.51,742.12,619.74,662.95,665.18,781.29
>   Cacna1e,2.448,1.981,1.506,2.003,1.318,3.052,1.953,0.814,2.17,2.482
>   Bdnf(2),1.853,2.128,2.553,1.996,0.663,2.5,2.385,0.468,1.922,1.481
>   Fos,18.402,24.653,23.038,20.615,8.027,38.444,20.836,11.756,20.823,20.296
>   Scn4b,23.772,27.874,25.388,25.109,51.926,20.291,25.521,28.701,30.256,17.344
>   Slc6a2(3),480.05,455.95,307.6,186.82,376.96,447.61,123.5,409.58,347.86,681.04
>   Ntf3(3),1.87,3.561,2.421,3.133,2.134,2.327,1.712,2.32,1.735,3.497
>   Bdnf(3),0.319,0.09,0.665,0.187,0.107,0.185,0.394,0.264,0.21,0.345
>   Scn3b,112.86,115.29,99.711,96.245,71.741,122.34,85.875,88.906,102.88,132.13
>   Grin2c,14.224,15.944,15.473,21.936,32.732,13.98,20.168,23.958,14.541,17.402
>   Gabrd,0.701,3.542,0.532,5.222,5.593,0.133,2.954,0.961,0.506,2.152
>   Cacna1b,16.935,15.764,14.475,15.639,10.655,19.408,14.115,14.079,14.26,16.737
>   Slc18a2,433.92,429.22,293.57,164.53,287.51,370.72,93.973,283.12,321.49,551.07
>   Cacnb1(2),16.456,5.099,16.969,4.469,12.471,5.143,14.017,10.049,17.537,4.26
>   Gabrg1,40.614,37.373,43.103,39.253,47.768,41.202,51.665,37.74,42.17,39.097
>   Grin1,1.235,0.812,0.909,1.605,0.513,1.371,1.596,1.346,1.213,0.922
>   Slc6a2(2),138.21,136.75,34.759,38.393,25.89,87.126,0,0.467,99.703,137.66
>   Galr3,2.691,2.51,2.517,4.446,0.727,2.933,4.041,2.08,2.638,1.456
>   Oprm1(3),7.273,7.676,7.08,6.196,5.515,9.023,2.57,4.8,7.699,10.471
>   Gabrq,70.623,67.728,51.095,42.456,43.156,77.924,28.63,32.975,54.192,87.697
>   Gria4(3),25.846,26.045,24.37,37.866,18.037,26.907,31.423,21.292,26.795,24.642
>   Cacna1c(2),0.644,0.894,0.831,1.084,0.721,1.026,0.817,0.371,1.333,1.015
>   Cacna1d(3),0.299,0.406,0.127,0.319,0.319,0.231,0.178,0.075,0.18,0.405
>   Cacnb1,47.24,51.505,42.702,48.718,33.28,60.334,38.611,41.827,40.352,56.132
>   Scn7a,2.351,2.38,2.114,1.96,0.316,2.647,1.945,1.219,2.559,1.498
>   Cacna1d,2.661,2.733,2.714,2.649,2.403,2.923,3.216,2.768,2.401,2.302
>   Gabra2,25.209,26.731,23.249,25.599,20.17,22.928,24.072,18.664,23.808,23.306
>   Scn9a,3.209,3.106,3.212,3.206,1.094,3.35,3.994,1.934,2.883,2.046
>   Ntf3(2),2.347,2.282,2.112,1.025,1.762,2.029,0.501,1.652,2.717,1.982
>   Gria2,12.726,12.997,12.74,15.615,7.156,14.375,13.387,11.682,12.968,11.332
>   Bdnf,0.703,0.777,1.034,0.571,0.166,1.164,0.549,0.325,0.801,1.12
>   Gria2(2),17.769,17.694,16.62,18.603,11.295,19.926,18.044,13.594,16.946,17.712
>   Bdnf(5),1.321,2.152,1.882,2.397,1.598,3.072,3.038,1.53,2.04,1.464

Comment: perhaps you mean `x <- t.test(x,y)`?  And I don't recommend re-using the variable name `x`

Comment: I think you have your row- and column-indexing backwards (`goi[row,column]`); you have identified your first 5 *rows* as `control` and the next 5 *rows* as `stress`, and you are trying to access 92 *columns*.

Comment: You'll also run into the problem that you are over-writing `x` each time in the loop. Perhaps this is a good time to mention that `for` loops don't "return" or remember that value like you want. This may be good opportunity for `results <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(goi2)), function(i) t.test(control[i,], stress[i,]))`.

Comment: Trying to do this *within* a dataframe will most likely require the use of tools like tidyr, dplyr, purrr, tibble etc., which may not be the best solution for you as you say you're new to R. I would suggest taking out what you want as two seperate vectors and running the t-tests on these, i.e. `x <- df$var_1[1:5]; y <- df$var_1[6:10]; t.test(x, y)`, where `df`is your dataframe and `var_1`is the variable with the values you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working sample using just base R. Using your `goi`:

```
str(goi)
# 'data.frame': 92 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ Gene  : chr  "Oprd1" "Grin2a" "Grin2d(2)" "Oprm1" ...
#  $ Rat_1 : num  2.75 3.13 4.5 2 137.35 ...
#  $ Rat_2 : num  1.39 2.64 5.53 1.8 97.16 ...
#  $ Rat_3 : num  2.25 2.96 2.63 1.61 113.65 ...
#  $ Rat_4 : num  3.36 5.17 4.68 1.71 141.93 ...
#  $ Rat_5 : num  3.19 2.48 3.93 3.67 77.3 ...
#  $ Rat_6 : num  2.43 3.54 6.05 3.21 133.02 ...
#  $ Rat_7 : num  1.985 2.596 0.98 0.249 88.872 ...
#  $ Rat_8 : num  1.75 1.535 0.077 1.248 75.586 ...
#  $ Rat_9 : num  2.75 3.2 4.38 1.76 108.96 ...
#  $ Rat_10: num  1.77 2.23 2.33 2.67 97.63 ...
control <- goi[,2:6]
stress <- goi[,7:11]
```

Now, instead of using `for` loop and processing each return as we calculate it, let's calculate everything, store the complete object for each test within the `list`, and preserve the opportunity to grab whatever we want from all tests afterwards.

```
results <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(goi)),
                  function(i) t.test(control[i,], stress[i,]))
length(results)
# [1] 92
```

Each element of `results` is the return value from a single call of `t.test`.

```
results[[1]]
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# data:  control[i, ] and stress[i, ]
# t = 1.1034, df = 6.2218, p-value = 0.3107
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.5386851  1.4374851
# sample estimates:
# mean of x mean of y 
#    2.5874    2.1380
```

You can access any component of the test results:

```
names(results[[1]])
# [1] "statistic"   "parameter"   "p.value"     "conf.int"    "estimate"   
# [6] "null.value"  "alternative" "method"      "data.name"  
head( sapply(results, `[[`, "p.value") )
# [1] 0.3107098 0.3083295 0.2626753 0.6245368 0.4406157 0.2800657
head( t(sapply(results, `[[`, "conf.int")) )
#             [,1]       [,2]
# [1,]  -0.5386851  1.4374851
# [2,]  -0.7513650  2.0681650
# [3,]  -1.5018657  4.4862657
# [4,]  -1.1880098  1.8504098
# [5,] -23.5402499 48.8678499
# [6,]  -2.2762668  0.8250668
```

NB: one of R's many nuances is the fact that the `*apply` family will return a matrix that some might think is transposed from what it *should* be. Because f this, calls that return a `matrix` will benefit from being sandwiched in `t(...)`. (This is a great opportunity to press the "I Believe" button and move on.)

You can combine all of these results into a single `data.frame` with something like:

```
namefunc <- function(x, nameroot) { dimnames(x) <- list(NULL, paste0(nameroot, seq_len(ncol(x)))) ; x ; }
```

(That was a small helper function to make the following slightly easier to read. It's a very naïve naming convention, used only to keep the columns unique for now.)

```
test_results <- cbind.data.frame(
  statistic = sapply(results, `[[`, "statistic"),
  p.value = sapply(results, `[[`, "p.value"),
  parameter = sapply(results, `[[`, "parameter"),
  namefunc( t(sapply(results, `[[`, "conf.int")), "conf" ),
  namefunc( t(sapply(results, `[[`, "estimate")), "est" )
)
head(test_results)
#    statistic   p.value parameter       conf1      conf2     est1     est2
# 1  1.1033554 0.3107098  6.221806  -0.5386851  1.4374851   2.5874   2.1380
# 2  1.0948456 0.3083295  7.312678  -0.7513650  2.0681650   3.2784   2.6200
# 3  1.2480711 0.2626753  5.480699  -1.5018657  4.4862657   4.2546   2.7624
# 4  0.5107431 0.6245368  7.337202  -1.1880098  1.8504098   2.1594   1.8282
# 5  0.8134064 0.4406157  7.633546 -23.5402499 48.8678499 113.4766 100.8128
# 6 -1.2161356 0.2800657  4.824393  -2.2762668  0.8250668   1.2900   2.0156
```

There is definitely room here to use packages from the `tidyverse` as RobertMc suggested. For that, I recommend `dplyr` and `tidyr`, though perhaps `broom` has utility here as well.

Comment: I know it diverges a little from your initial attempt, but does this answer your questions? If so, please "accept" the answer (checkmark to the left of the answer).